# How to install version 5.1 on Windows 10 VirtualBox

Tags: system-installation, microsoft-windows, virtualbox

I am getting stuck on the screen where you tell Elementary that you want to install updates and third party software. I've tried with none of the options on the screen chosen, and it still gets stuck.

[image]

On a side note, I also had issues installing Elementary 5.1 on Windows 10's Hyper-V. It would never actually get to the point where it booted up the image. I will search the forum for help there.

Comment: Is it because I have Hyper-V running as well? I figured that it wouldn't even get me to the point of booting the image if that was the case. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through and followed the directions that VMWare provides to disable Device Guard. Looks like it's going to work - past where I got with VirtualBox.

Comment: I got it working just fine with VMware player. VirtualBox, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this

[elementary os on virtual box](https://24itworld.wordpress.com/2016/07/12/virtualization-first-steps-with-oracle-virtualbox/)

its usually a straight foward task, have to ask, are you using a 32bit or 64bit? can that be and issue?

Lastely I would suggest using vmware player (free for personal and non-comercial use) and performance is better.

Comment: I  am using 64-bit. I'll check out that link now.

Comment: I tried VMWare Player. No luck. Now I get a new error about running some Device Guard garbage that comes with Windows Defender. I've never ever ever had issues installing VMs in the past.

Comment: Are you still struggling to install? where are you stuck now?